# Youtube Reporting API returns video data but Youtube Data API does not for specific channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have this issue where a specific channel is not returning any videos on the Data-API (see response from API below):

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "YIUPVpqNjppyCWOZfL-19bLb7uk",
    "items": [],
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 0
    }
}
```

In the meanwhile I can see data on its videos on Reporting API, both for Combined A2 and Basic A2 report types, like below (anonymized):

```
date,channel_id,video_id,live_or_on_demand,subscribed_status,country_code,views,comments,likes,dislikes,shares,watch_time_minutes,average_view_duration_seconds,average_view_duration_percentage,annotation_impressions,annotation_clickable_impressions,annotation_clicks,annotation_click_through_rate,annotation_closable_impressions,annotation_closes,annotation_close_rate,card_teaser_impressions,card_teaser_clicks,card_teaser_click_rate,card_impressions,card_clicks,card_click_rate,subscribers_gained,subscribers_lost,videos_added_to_playlists,videos_removed_from_playlists,red_views,red_watch_time_minutes
20221018,CHANNEL_ID,VIDEO_ID,on_demand,not_subscribed,FR,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The request done to Data API has the following `parts` specified: `snippet,contentDetails,statistics,id,topicDetails` (independent of parts the request yields an empty answer as well)

```
Channel ID: UCs5DLbzGZJ559lKPP2pEWCw
Playlist ID: UUs5DLbzGZJ559lKPP2pEWCw
```

Tried calling Data API with third party token, with channel's token, checked on Reporting API (there is data there but not on Data API).

I expected: that videos are listed in Data API's PlaylistItems.list edge.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUs5DLbzGZJ559lKPP2pEWCw&key=API_KEY returns some videos on my end, isn't it on yours?

Comment: I was able to now get playlist items. Checking on /videos now.

Thanks a lot.